# Backup Software Sources

Tags: ubuntu

In Ubuntu 10.04, when I goto System > Administration > Software Sources and goto the Authentication tab, I can view all of my keys allowing me to download from third party sources.

How would I back this up to copy all of my sources and keys to a new system?

Answer (score 1):

Should all be in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but I'd check...